# How to remove gap at end of ggplot2 graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

My input file is [here on PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/CXneq6yc).

My current graph code is:

```
 #Input and data formatting
 merg_agg_creek<-read.table("merged aggregated creek.txt",header=TRUE)
 library(ggplot2)
 library(grid)
 source("http://egret.psychol.cam.ac.uk/statistics/R/extensions/rnc_ggplot2_border_themes.r")

 CombinedCreek<-data.frame(merg_agg_creek)
 Combined<-CombinedCreek[order(CombinedCreek[,2]),]
 Combined$Creek <- factor(rep(c('Culvert Creek','North Silcox','South Silcox','Yucca Pen'),c(32,57,51,31)))  
 Combined$Creek<-factor(Combined$Creek,levels(Combined$Creek)[c(1,4,3,2)])

 #The Graph Code

 creek <-ggplot(Combined,aes(Month,Density,color=factor(Year),shape=factor(Year)))+scale_color_discrete("Year")+scale_shape_discrete("Year")
 creek<-creek + facet_grid(Creek~. ,scales = "free_y")
 creek <- creek + geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = .3))
 creek<-creek+scale_color_grey("Year",end=.6)+theme_bw()
 creek<-creek+scale_y_continuous(expression("Number of prey captured " (m^2) ^-1))
 creek<-creek+opts( panel.border = theme_L_border() )+ opts(axis.line = theme_segment())
 creek<-creek+opts(panel.grid.minor = theme_blank())+opts(panel.grid.major = theme_blank())
 creek<-creek+scale_x_discrete("Month",breaks=c(2,5,8,11),labels=c("February","May","August","November"))
 creek
```

The resulting graph is: 
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGBTL.jpg)
[image: graph]

My issue is that by creating the breaks and labels in "scale_x_discrete", a large gap exists on the righthand side of the plot, between the data in December and the facet labels.  I tried eliminating this gap by adding "limits=c(0,13)" to the "scale_x_discrete: command, but the [resulting graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aK3z.jpg) destroys the x-labels.

How do I remove that gap?  Is there something fundamentally flawed in my plot creation?

Thanks!

EDIT:  Didzis answered the question below.  I just need to change from scale_x_discrete to scale_x_continuous

Comment: Try replace scale_x_dicrete() with scale_x_continuous(), leaving all other parameters the same

Comment: Great! Thanks.  Was hoping it was a simple answer.

Comment: @Didzis, post as answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the Month in your data is numerical, try replace

```
 scale_x_discrete("Month",breaks=c(2,5,8,11),labels=c("February","May","August","November"))
```

with

```
 scale_x_continuous("Month",breaks=c(2,5,8,11),labels=c("February","May","August","November"))
```

leaving all other parameters the same

Comment: Thanks for posting this Didzis

Comment: I have a very similar graph, but when I replace scale_x_discrete with scale_x_continuous, I get this error:
`Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`
(to me, this error makes sense)

Comment: Then your x values are not numeric.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the expand argument in the scale. I think the extra space might be due to the jitter, but if you give it a -2 it goes all the way to the edge. Almost seems like a bug that it's padding so much.

```
ggplot(Combined,aes(Month,Density,color=factor(Year),shape=factor(Year))) +
scale_shape_discrete("Year") +
facet_grid(Creek~. ,scales = "free_y") +
geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = .3)) +
scale_color_grey("Year",end=.6) +
theme_bw() +
scale_y_continuous(expression("Number of prey captured " (m^2) ^-1))+
scale_x_discrete("Month",breaks=c(2,5,8,11),labels=c("February","May","August","November"), expand= c(0,-2)) +
theme(
panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor=element_blank()
)
```